# singularity: WARNING: Skipping mount /etc/localtime [binds]: /etc/localtime doesn't exist in container

Tags: singularity-container

I created a local singularity image such like:

```
singularity pull --arch amd64 library://library/default/ubuntu:18.04
sudo singularity build --sandbox cellranger.img ubuntu_18.04.sif
```

But I got two warnings by running `singularity shell`

```
sudo singularity shell --writable cellranger.img
WARNING: Skipping mount /etc/localtime [binds]: /etc/localtime doesn't exist in container
WARNING: Skipping mount /data/github/singularity [cwd]: /data/dz33/github/singularity doesn't exist in container
Singularity>
```

Where `/data/github/singularity` is the current directory.

I am wondering why the directory was skipped for mounting (if I understand the warnings correctly). Some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning happens when you attempt to mount a file or directory into the image without a file/directory with that name already there, and you're either using an older kernel that doesn't support overlay or using the `--writable` tag. [See documentation on the `--writable` issue, which is what you're having.](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html?highlight=overlay#a-note-on-using-bind-with-the-writable-flag)

The lack of `/etc/localtime` in the image is a bit odd, but you can work around the `cwd` mount using the following: `-H $PWD:/home`. That mounts the current directory to `/home` and uses it as your `$HOME`.

Comment: I have used the --writable tag but still get the warning. My singularity version is 3.5.2.

Comment: And that tag is precisely the issue. Per the docs, which I recommend reading, mount in a directory that is writable and use that instead. Or use `--writable`, but make sure that all the files/directories exist before they're mounted in. The first is much simpler.